# Proving limits exists using epsilon definition

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Proving a limit exists.

I have found the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x\sin{x}}{x^{2}+1} = 0$. By the sandwich theorem however I have decided that I want to prove that this is the case, ie. I want to show that given $\varepsilon>0$, I want to find $M>0$ s.t. $$\forall x>M \implies |f(x)-0|<\varepsilon.$$

I have real problems trying to actually spot how to simplify these into something I can actually work with, can someone give me any tips?

First I note that $$|f(x)|=\left|\frac{x\sin{x}}{x^{2}+1}\right| \ge \left|\frac{-x}{x^{2}+1}\right| = \left| \frac{x}{x^{2}+1}\right|$$ Now I don't really have any idea how to progress here.

I was thinking letting $$\left|\frac{x}{x^{2}+1}\right|>\left|\frac{x}{x^{2}+x^{2}}\right| = \left|\frac{1}{2x}\right|<\varepsilon$$ for $x>1$ which implies $|x|>1/2\varepsilon$ so taking $M=\max{\left(\frac{1}{2\varepsilon},1\right)}$ we can conclude this limit exists. Is this correct?

Comment: You don't need $|x|>M$, just $x>M$. $x\to\infty$ means $x\to +\infty$, unless otherwise stated somewhere.

Comment: Hi, I have edited the post can you confirm if it is correct? I agree with what you have stated above however it doesn't really make a difference too much does it?

Comment: Not sure what you edited, but not what I was talking  about. It is not true that $|f(x)|\geq \left|\frac{x}{x^2+1}\right|$ however.

Comment: Ok, I have made it $x>M$, why not? We have $\sin{x}\ge-1$ $\forall x$ thus $x\sin{x}\ge-x$, then $|x\sin{x}|\ge|-x|=|x|$ by applying the modulus. I'm guessing we can't do this with the modulus?

Comment: $u\geq v$ does not mean $|u|\geq |v|$. Try $u=-2$ and $v=-4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that we want to find an **upper** bound, so your inequalities are facing the wrong way.

---

Given any $\varepsilon > 0$, let $M = \frac{1}{\varepsilon} > 0$. Then for all $x > M$, observe that:
\begin{align*}
|f(x) - 0|
&= \left|\frac{x \sin x}{x^{2}+1}\right| \\
&= \left|\frac{x}{x^{2}+1}\right| \cdot |\sin x| \\
&\leq \left|\frac{x}{x^{2}+0}\right| \cdot 1 \\
&= \frac{1}{x} &\text{since } x > M > 0 \implies \frac{1}{x} > 0 \implies \left|\frac{1}{x} \right| = \frac{1}{x}\\
&< \varepsilon &\text{since } x > M = \frac{1}{\varepsilon} \iff \varepsilon > \frac{1}{x}
\end{align*}
as desired. $~~\blacksquare$

Comment: This is actually the answer my calculation got. Just think-in the Good Old Days,students used to do problems like this in COLLEGE CALCULUS.

Comment: Hi, this doesn't seem to be correct because you have found $|f(x)-0|\le 1/x$ but since you have made $1/x$ greater than $|f(x)-0|$ you no longer know if it is less than $\varepsilon$. So your final line seems incorrect to me, can you explain it please? Thanks.

Comment: Suppose that $x > M$. Then since $M = \frac{1}{\varepsilon}$, we know that $x > \frac{1}{\varepsilon}$. Multiplying both sides by $\varepsilon$, we get that $x\cdot\varepsilon > 1$. Dividing both sides by $x$, we get that $\varepsilon > \frac{1}{x}$ so that $\frac{1}{x} < \varepsilon$. So $|f(x) - 0| \leq \frac{1}{x} < \varepsilon$, as desired.

Comment: Given the $M=\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ he found, is it not true that $|f(x)|<\epsilon$ for $x>M$? What exactly is the problem? @user2850514

Comment: I'm just really confused. We start with $|f(x)-0|<\varepsilon$ then we want to rearrange this to the form $x>M$ therefore conclude that $M=$our new right-hand-side. I understand up until his third line but then he bounds it from above rather than below but surely if he bounds it from above we no longer know if our new bound is less than $\varepsilon$.

Comment: Would it be a pain in me asking you to go through this question assuming you didn't know what $M$ was initially as that is what I have to assume.

Comment: We don't start out with $|f(x)-0|<\epsilon$. That is your confusion. You want $x>M$ to imply $|f(x)-0|<\epsilon$. @user2850514

Comment: Hi Thomas, ok thanks, how do we start from $x>M$ when we don't know what $M$ is at first? In Adriano's answer it seems as if he has started with $|f(x)-0|$?

Comment: I have made a new question with what seems to be my main problem:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1074013/proving-limits-using-epsilon-definition

Answer (score 2):

You have it exactly backwards. $$\left|f(x)\right|=|\sin x|\left|\frac{x}{1+x^2}\right|<1\cdot \left|\frac 1x\right|$$

So $|f(x)|<\epsilon$ for $x>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$.

You've mistakenly determined that, if $\sin x \geq -1$ then $|\sin x|\geq 1$, which is absurd, since we know that $|\sin x|\leq 1$.

In general, if $u\geq v$, it is not true that $|u|\geq |v|$. Try $u=2,v=-4$.

Comment: Nice answer,but I think Adriano's version of the same response below is a little more complete.

Comment: True, but I also note OPs error, which I think is actually more important. @Mathemagician1234